# Solving without induction

Tags: trigonometry, products

$$\prod_{k=1}^n\cos\frac{x}{2^k}=\frac{\sin{x}}{2^n\sin\frac{x}{2^n}}$$
I tried to prove this without induction, but I can't come up with any idea. My teacher solved it with induction, which is the easy way, but she suggested us to try to solve it using a trigonometric trick. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: $\cos\frac{x}{2^k}\sin\frac{x}{2^k}=\dfrac{\sin\frac{x}{2^{k-1}}}{2}$,so on and so on...

Comment: @chenbai: I would have thought that was the induction step

Comment: You derive a relation  between sinx and sin(x/2^n). You will get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: With the double angle formula, one can show that

$$\cos\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2^{n-1}}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)}$$

If you multiply consecutive terms of the LHS, some cancellation on the RHS occurs to give the desired identity.

---

(I confess taking this from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morrie%27s_law).)